# WebClient.DownloadString("Website.com/text.txt") returns html

Tags: c#, string, web, webclient, downloadstring

So I FTP uploaded a text file to my website, my website displays the text perfectly and accepts the format however whenever I do webclient.downloadstring it returns this:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7ebbeaac07f92b3673f9cfa10425d300");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://www.braintrail.byethost7.com/Projects/submission.txt?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the response in detail, you'll see this line:

```
location.href="http://www.braintrail.byethost7.com/Projects/submission.txt?i=1";
```

When I visit `bytehost7.com` I get directed to a spam fake virus infection report page. Though when I retrieve `www.braintrail.byethost7.com/Projects/submission.txt?i=1` directly I get the text file you uploaded.

If I didn't know better, I'd say you have a malicious webhost which hides resources and/or has had their own website hacked to display those fake virus messages.

Solution: get a better webhost.

Also, FTP is obsolete and insecure.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! Could you suggest other resources instead of FTP (I programtically uploaded by the way).